# How to deliberately refresh or crash browser tab using response from AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome, safari

Yesterday we pushed code to production that included a polling mechanism (via `setInterval()` in Javascript) that makes an AJAX request every 15 seconds to keep the clients up-to-date with the server. Although only about 450 people were using our site at any given time today, it seems many of our users keep our site open even when they're not using it. Like, a lot of users.

Within 12 hours on a Sunday, we had effectively DDoS'd ourselves. About 3,500 people had left our site open on their browsers, meaning 200 requests per second to this PHP endpoint. With a KeepAlive of 5, this triggered our Apache server to quickly hit its MaxClients limit, which choked new connections from being established, causing random errors for existing users, etc. We raised that limit and lowered the KeepAlive time without issue, but the real fix came an hour later when we changed the `setInterval()` to also consider `document.visibilityState == "visible"`, so that backgrounded tabs won't hammer our server with polling. (In case you're wondering by this point, we will be moving to silent push notifications instead of polling even sooner than we were planning after this experience).

That fix should work for new users, but it leaves us with those 3,500 users who still have our site open on their computer with the bad code that is indiscriminately hitting us with requests even when they're not using the site. We need them to get the new code ASAP to stop the DDoS, or induce their tab to freeze so that the web requests from their browser stop. We've tested a couple ideas on Chrome and Safari, but none of them worked.

The first was inducing a page refresh via PHP's `header("Refresh:0");`. We tried including a couple of variations of this in our endpoint, but it doesn't seem like a response header from an AJAX request can induce a page refresh. We also tried responding to the request with HTML `echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">';` but that didn't work either, possibly because the AJAX request is expecting JSON, not HTML, and changing the content type of the response wasn't enough.

The second was to crash the page by overloading the response to this endpoint with data. We tried adding multiple `bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(5000000))`s to the response as variables that get written to local storage in the browser. This did get the browser to freeze and use up to 1GB of RAM, but even with the interface completely unresponsive, the tab didn't "crash" and web requests continued going out, so this method didn't work either.

**Update:** a third thing we tried was doing a `sleep(9999999)` in the PHP file that they're hitting. Since browsers will only will make up to 6 simultaneous requests to a given domain, we figure once these clients have made 6 requests to the endpoint, further requests will not be made since these 6 will hang indefinitely. We tried pushing this to production and things didn't go well: within 30 seconds Apache was even more overloaded than before, since now the requests were piling up without finishing. So we had to restart Apache (which in-turn cancelled all the hung requests, returning us back to the prior state). We think some variation of employing the fact that a browser will only make up to 6 simultaneous requests to a domain might work, but we're not sure how to do use that fact.

What else can we try?

Comment: If you need continues live updates, don't use AJAX! Seriously, you're asking for trouble here as you've already experienced. And crashing the client's browser as a "solution" is just not done at all. Instead, you should be using a websocket. Since you're using PHP, you can even include ReactPHP and have a timeout setup to disconnect inactive clients from the socket. I suggest you take a look at [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) which also already includes ReactPHP.

Comment: Certainly don't disagree we were asking for trouble with this polling business! As I said, we're going to look into silent push notifications (or web sockets) as a means of clients getting updates, but we have to resolve this crisis before we can even consider pushing new code.

Comment: Did you check the website I linked? The documentation part has [Push Integration](http://socketo.me/docs/push) It's a simple / fast / easily deplorable solution for already existing websites that rely on Ajax to mitigate the problem until you're ready with a new codebase.

Comment: Ah wait.. I seem to understand the issue now. There are many clients passively pulling because they didn't refresh in ages. That one is a bit more tricky. I'd probably update the client side code and implement some variable that lets your server know whether it's updated or not. If not, just exit before your server does anything. That way all the outstanding, old requests shouldn't harm your server resources any longer

Comment: @icecub yeah, that's exactly what we just did this morning. We even made it so that if the users go back to the page and try to use the site again, they'll see a message that says "please refresh your browser" instead of the content they want to see. Unfortunately, only 5% of people who have the bad client side code have actually come back to their tab, seen our message, and refreshed the page. Obviously this will improve with time, but it could take weeks, so we're trying to figure out a way that doesn't require user interaction.

Answer (score 3):

(I'm too new to comment, so I have to make this into an answer)

Often handling a request at server level, rather than at application level is at least an order of magnitude cheaper. Given that your application likely hits the database, restores the session, does a bunch of routing and so before getting to the point where you can reject the request.

I would still suggest deprecating the problematic url.
If you return a HTTP 410 GONE instead of a 404
and you add cache control headers, you might convince the browser to serve the results from cache instead of actually making the call.

Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000

This assumes that you use didn't use a cache buster parameter in your polling mechanism of course. If every url is new and unique, caching won't save you.

Comment: We didn't get a chance to try this during the height of the issue, but this seems like a really good idea, and may have been a solution for us!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest pushing a new version of the website with a changed url for the ajax request. After that you can add a rewrite rule to your .htaccess causing the old ajax url to return a 404 instead of being handled by your PHP application.
This should relieve the pressure.
Good luck!

Comment: A new version will not help — the question is about old versions that are still open and not being interacted with at all, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @Kevin Reid is right, this will not help (at least, it won't help much). Mathias almost has it, but the issue with this is sending a 404 still requires Apache to serve the request and use resources. It's not our PHP application that's getting overwhelmed, it's Apache.